# node.js request handler wont call a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am taking first steps in node.js and came across an issue when trying to rout request my server receives. 
i have the following files in my project, all in the same level of hierarchy:

server.js:

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');

function start(route,handle){
    function onRequest(request, response) {
        var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
        console.log("Request for " + pathname + " received");

        route(handle,pathname);

        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        response.write("Hello World");
        response.end();
        }
    http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
    console.log("Server has started.")
}

exports.start = start;
```

requestHandlers.js:

```
function start(){
    console.log("Request handler 'start' was called");
}

function upload(){
    console.log("Request handler 'upload' was called");
}

exports.start = start;
exports.upload = upload;
```

router.js:

```
function route(handle,pathname){
    console.log("About to route a request for" + pathname );
    if (typeof handle[pathname] === 'function'){
        handle[pathname];
    } else {
        console.log('No request handler found for' + pathname);
    }
}

exports.route = route;
```

and the last one is index.js:

```
var server = require('./server');
var router = require('./router');
var requestHandlers = require('./requestHandlers');


var handle = {};
handle["/"] = requestHandlers.start;
handle["/start"] = requestHandlers.start;
handle["/upload"] = requestHandlers.upload;


server.start(router.route,handle);
```

when i type in my browser the URL "localhot:8888/start" for example, i get this in the console:

```
Server has started.
Request for /upload received
About to route a request for/upload
Request for /favicon.ico received
About to route a request for/favicon.ico
No request handler found for/favicon.ico
```

but why want i see the console.log i expected to see from the `upload()` or `start()`functions?

thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be because you never invoke your start or upload functions.  Try adding some parentheses after handle[pathname] in router.js like this:

```
function route(handle,pathname){
    console.log("About to route a request for" + pathname );
    if (typeof handle[pathname] === 'function'){
        handle[pathname]();
    } else {
        console.log('No request handler found for' + pathname);
    }
}

exports.route = route;
```

Hope this helps.